# Equivalent of a popover in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, popover, sktilemapnode

I'm using Swift 5, SpriteKit, SKTileMap. I would like to use the equivalent of a popover. I'm using this term, because I use popovers rather frequently in other apps. Basically, a small window appears, and you read something and press OK, or maybe add a little information and press OK. What I'm trying to figure out how to do is something similar in SpriteKit.

The objective is, I want a user to long press a tile, and a small box pops up with information about the tile. What is the terrain? What resources are there? Is there a city? Is a player there? etc. It doesn't HAVE to be a view, but I'm guessing that's the way to go, because not only could there be quite a bit of text, I could see there being a button to dismiss, and maybe some tiny graphics, like a symbol corresponding to the resource, etc. Here's what I have already. I have a working long press gesture recognizer. I can already print all of the information I want to the console on the simulator. What I need to figure out is a few things.

1. required: create the window and fill it with information.
2. optional: anchor to tile and/or center in the screen. I haven't decided best solution yet.
3. optional: dim background (probably just some alpha tweak)

The current code I have actually works very smooth. I have a good camera pinch to zoom and a good pan gesture. I load my map from a JSON file. I actually load it into a core data, database, and draw from a query against the database. That way, if you do any action, it just hits the database. What's on tile 5,5? just query the database. It works nice. I just don't know how to do the popover window in SpriteKit. I tried adding an actual popover to the content view my map is in, but it just dims the screen a little. I don't think that's a good anchor.

Comment: I sort of solved my question overnight. I added a toolbar to the view controller that has the container view for my SpriteKit map. I was going to add this toolbar anyway, and it provides a good anchor for the popover view. The current configuration is MapViewController, with MapViewController.swift handling it's code. Then there's a MapScene.swift that's the SpriteKit implementation. The contentView is SKView. If I hear nothing else, I'll use the current solution, because I can customize a popover view a lot, which is what I want for information box. If you have other clever ideas, let me know

Answer (score 1):

in HIG "Human Interface Guidelines" they are called "Alert" or Alert sheet and you can create an alert using simple code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Did you bring your towel?", message: "It's recommended you bring your towel before continuing.", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

you can learn more how to Programme,style etc  from  this link https://learnappmaking.com/uialertcontroller-alerts-swift-how-to/